# Is there a way to pip install PythonDecoratorLibrary?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Here is a link: [PythonDecoratorLibrary](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary)

Or is it supposed to be a reusable chunks of code that one uses without a pip installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a collection of code samples listed on the page for people to use, not a package that you can install. Library in the collection of books sense, not the code sense :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. It's not installable, it's a wiki page, that, quote, says

> This page is meant to be a central repository of decorator code pieces, whether useful or not .